# How to config Webpack build to get assets generated in public folder?

Tags: webpack

When I build my project using webpack, it publishes all files in dist folder. I want HTML file and asset files to be published in public folder. How do I configure webpack to achieve this?

webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: { minimize: true }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: do you want this dist add in the folder public

Comment: No. I want js file only in dist folder; all other files in public folder.

Comment: try to add path  const path = require('path');
in the module.exports = {...
//add this code
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './locatinfoldr'),
    filename: 'what youname'



}

Answer (score 0):

**outputPath** can be used to achieve this.

File loader configuration can be changed to:

```
`{
  test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: { outputPath: '../public' },
},`
```

Since public and dist folders are at same level, ../public is used.